# EF5 - Counting children and grandchildren - Simplify my linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have read many posts here on stack overflow on counting children and grandchildren of a entity.

My entity hierarchy is

```
Clients -> Locations -> Users
```

I have written the following LINQ lambda expression and it works perfectly well.

```
int locations = _clientRepository.Clients
                    .Where(x => (x.ClientId == id))
                    .Select(x => x.Locations.Count())
                    .First();

int users     = _clientRepository.Clients
                    .Where(x => (x.ClientId == id))
                    .Select(x => x.Locations.Sum(l => l.Applicants.Count()))
                    .First();
```

I just feel like there is a way to simplify it just a bit further.  The First method seems like it should be unnecessary, but I was just curious if there was a better way to write it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds more like you need to check out [codereview.se]

Comment: I am already, I just simplified it for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int number1 = myClientRepository
    .Clients
    .Where(x => x.ClientId == Id)
    .First()
    .Locations
    .Count;

int User1 = myClientRepository.Clients
    .Where(x => x.ClientId == Id)
    .First()
    .Locations.Sum(x => x.Applicants.Count);
```

Comment: Thanks!! You can even change the 'Where' to 'First' and reduce it even further.  Unfortunately, when using this inside of my MVC EF5 project, it returns 0 instead of the 6 that LinqPad is giving me.  So you definitely answered my question and gave me the result I was looking for.  I just have to figure out why it doesn't work in C#